# Straight rotation on non straight Axis

Tags: game-engine, transforms

[image: Intended rotation]

Hello, i have this model that i am trying to program on BGE, as you can see in the first gif the claw is rotating correctly on Y axis, but when i move the sphere  to a non 90 degree angle on the z axis the claw rotate very weird(i know that is intended to do that due to how the program handles the space), how i can make it rotate straight on the Y Axis like  the first gif even when its not in a 90 degree on Z axis?.
PD: Sorry for my English, i am from Chile South America

[image: issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hit the axis key twice instead of once. This will make it rotate in local instead of world space.

(P.S.:  Your English is perfectly fine. Also, just as a helpful tip—if you need an exact rotation, you can always type numbers instead of dragging the mouse.)

Comment: Not working :/ , i want it to rotate exactly as the first gift, if i am in 45º in Z axis, is still rotating weirdly in the y or x axis, i want to make it rotate like if i were on 0 º on the Z axis, straight claw up and down

Comment: Whoops, gave wrong directions. Hit the _axis_ key twice, not the R key. (Updating answer now.)

Comment: OH its working :D, thank you so much, another small thing, how i can define it on the script to rotate on local instead of world space?

Comment: ``obj.applyRotation(Vector,local=True)`` [api reference](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=apply%20rotation#bge.types.KX_GameObject.applyRotation)